# Property value picker problem on non-IE browsers

Tags: user-profile-property, browser-compatibility, 2007

We have several profile properties that are set as multivalue fields and are restricted to a list of options. Some of them are set up as

Company Name
Company Name - Specific Department 1
Company Name - Specific Department 2

If a user tries to select "Company Name" using a non IE browser (I've tried Chrome, Firefox & Safari), they get an error message saying "more than one matched choices were found. click to resolve". Clicking does nothing.

It seems to be because it's conflicting with the specific department options, but there's no way to indicate that this is the option they want, whether using the "select property values" popup or by typing directly into the field.

We have several users who use Macs and therefore have no access to IE. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Microsoft only support what [they say they support](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526%28office.12%29.aspx). Ensure you are running Service Pack 2 for the best experience on SharePoint 2007, or even better upgrade to SharePoint 2010 which has much [better cross browser support](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx).